# NServicebus Saga using Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, nservicebus

I would like to know if it's possible to use Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore with NServicebus 7.6?
I am using hosted .NET 6 service running NSB 7.6.
Data access are using Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore

From the [documentation](https://docs.particular.net/persistence/sql/) it looks like you have to use NHibernate or "old" NET 4.x

Comment: Looks like from documentation: **No ORM dependency: can be used with Entity Framework, Dapper, etc.**

Comment: Looks like I should use the https://docs.particular.net/samples/sql-persistence/simple/#sql-scripts-persistence-config-oracle.
The example works fine

Answer (score 1):

There's [a sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/entity-framework-core/) for using Entity Framework Core and like Martin Anderson mentioned, you can use it together with [SQL Persistence for Oracle](https://docs.particular.net/samples/sql-persistence/simple/#sql-scripts-persistence-config-oracle) and share the connection. As the documentation mentions:

> To maintain consistency, the business data has to reuse the same connection context as NServiceBus persistence. With SQL persistence, this is achieved by using the same ADO.NET connection and transaction objects in both NServiceBus and Entity Framework.